# Libclang check syntax

Tags: c++, llvm, clang

Is there some way to get info from libclang whether C++ code in source file has correct syntax? Libclang tries to create translation unit even with not valid C++ code.

Answer (score 2):

The generic answer for the generic question is yes. Take a look at this Sublime Text plugin that uses libclang to do that: https://github.com/quarnster/SublimeClang.

It uses the libclang Python binding to process the current file in the editor and flag errors and warnings, as well as providing other useful features like auto-completion and 'Go to definition'.

Comment: +1 for the link to SublimeClang. It's been bloody murder getting a ``libclang.dll`` compiled on Windows 7. SublimeClang has precompiled DLLs for both 32- and 64-bit Windows, and doesn't have any dependencies on other LLVM libs. I'll need to figure out how to create these from pristine sources eventually, but using the libs from SublimeClang has really lowered the barrier to entry for me to start experimenting with clang's Python bindings.